# Is combining silicone plasters and silicone gels for scars effective?

Tags: dermatology, scar-tissue-scars, plastic-surgery, self-healing-repairing

I have a question. As far as I know, **silicone gels** and **silicone plasters (aka sheets or patches)** are used to optimize wound healing and minimize scarring. I purchased a silicone plaster ***Mepiform*** and silicone gel ***Strataderm*** against the scars.

---

Can they be used **simultaneously** to enhance their positive effect? That is, first you put the silicone gel on skin, let it dry and then on top of the dried gel you attach silicone plaster.

Will it be more effective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many factors that can determine how well an individual will heal and scar. While many treatments have been suggested for the treatment of scars, only a few of them have been supported by prospective studies with an adequate control group. As a result, the development of hypertrophic scars and keloids remains an unsolved problem in the process of wound healing. An abstract titled, ‘[The use of silicone occlusive sheeting (Sil-K) and silicone occlusive gel (Epiderm) in the prevention of hypertrophic scar formation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9810992?dopt=Abstract)' confirms,

> For this reason, a successful treatment to prevent excessive scar formation still has yet to be found.

Therefore, as it relates to the *effectiveness* of topical scar treatments -- there isn't one particular type that is *completely effective*. The potential for achieving results from a topical scar treatment is usually dependent on the age, thickness, and location of the scar.

However, clinical support of topical gel products, relative to all alternative scar therapies, is considered the "internationally recommended first-line form of scar management", though there continues to be ongoing deliberation over the exact mechanism of action of silicone in improving a scar. '[The Use of Silicone Adhesives for Scar Reduction](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4486716/)' explains,

> At present it is likely that through occlusion of the scar site and hydration of the wound bed, the overactivity of scar-related cells is suppressed, and their activity normalized.

Whereas occlusion and hydration may also be achieved by other scar care products, '[An Evaluation of Evidence Regarding Application of Silicone Gel Sheeting for the Management of Hypertrophic Scars and Keloids](http://europepmc.org/articles/PMC2989813;jsessionid=B8FC345F5F30BF514B5D53722310AA86)' recognizes the benefits of silicone gel sheeting, stating it

> …has been clinically proven to also address pruritus, skin pigmentation changes, and primary prevention...Hypertrophic and keloid scar-related physical discomfort ranging from itching to pain have been seen to improve dramatically upon SGS treatment.

Additional benefits include:

> ...no skin stripping, and no painful skin or hair pulling; but another advantage also lies in the fact that...unlike alternatives, have a low viscous component that limits their flow and consequently their readiness to absorb materials at the surface of the skin such as stratum corneum cells and lipids.  The adhesive surface...remains relatively clean and can be removed, reused and cleaned repeatedly without diminishing its integrity.
>
> ...used in scar treatment for more than 30 years, demonstrating safety and efficacy recognized by wound care professionals.
>
> ...silicone gel sheeting has been demonstrated to reduce incidence of hypertrophic scars.

The same abstract references several topical silicone-containing scar care products and, when comparing **silicone gel** and **silicone gel sheeting**, the limitations of silicone gel sheeting specifically

> ...can be cumbersome to keep on the scar, with some patients showing an aversion to wearing SGS in visible areas

On the other hand, silicone gel was said to have

> …a higher compliance than gel sheeting, due primarily to ease of use and convenience...[but] A few studies have suggested no significant difference between the gel and gel sheeting.

Although the abstract also confesses that additional studies are needed with all therapies used to treat scars, your question is still addressed to some degree.

> …**silicone gel sheeting can be employed, especially as an *adjunct in combination* with other hypertrophic scar and keloid treatments.**

Based on the provided information, you can *technically* use both topical scar treatments at the same time but may not receive an added benefit from the combination. Thus, using one or the other should be just as effective. The effectiveness of using one or both products will likely depend on your individual biology because (as with any therapy), individual responses and results may vary.

In conclusion, it is always in your best interest to consult with your primary care physician or dermatologist to discuss the best treatment option(s) for your specific condition and individual needs.

Comment: @Chichi You are quite welcome! Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Can [silicone gels and silicone plasters] be used simultaneously to enhance their positive effect?

No, according to [ScarAway's user manual](https://www.myscaraway.com/faq/#toggle-id-16) (ScarAway is one of the main brands for silicone gels and silicone sheets in the United States):

> Do not use [silicone gels and silicone sheets] at the same time.

I guess that the reason is that using silicone gels and silicone sheets (= plasters) at the same time would interfere with the adherence of the sheets to the skin, thereby reducing its effect.

However, as mentioned on https://www.myscaraway.com/faq/#toggle-id-16, you can use the silicone gel when not using the silicone sheets:

> Can I use ScarAway® Scar Diminishing Gel with ScarAway® Silicone Scar Sheets?Yes.  ScarAway® Scar Diminishing Gel may be used as part of your complete scar treatment regimen. Simply apply ScarAway® Scar Diminishing Gel as directed when not wearing your ScarAway® Silicone Sheet.

Note that ScarAway's packaging mentions:

> For best results: Use as part of a complete scar treatment regimen, alternating use with ScarAway Silicone Scar Sheets.

[image]

However no evidence is given of the usefulness of alternating Scar Sheets with gel and obviously, there could be a financial bias.

---

ScarAway's user manual:

[image]

[image]